# Computation complexity of this simple algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory

I calculate the optimal case complexity, average, and worst of this algorithm in java, I think if good is `O (1)` in the worst case is `O (n)`, but I do not know if average! could you help me on how to calculate it? thank you!

```
public boolean searchFalse(boolean[] b){ 
 boolean trovato=false; 
  for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
   if(b[i]==false){
 trovato=true;
 break;
   }
  }return trovato;
}
```

Comment: n i.e. equal to the length of b.

Comment: Simple evaluation of the complexity of some implemented procedure is made by way of nesting loops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't resist re-writing it

```
public boolean searchFalse(boolean[] bs){
    for (boolean b : bs) if(!b) return true;
    return false;
}
```

This stops after the first element potentially O(1).

If all the boolean are random the average search time is O(1) as you perform 2 searches on average, or if there is typically one false value in a random position the average is O(N)

If it has to search all the way, the worst case is O(N)

In short O(N/2) = O(N)

Comment: True only if there is only one "false" in the array. If each value as the same probability to be true/false, we have a O(1). So the O(N/2) is wrong without assumptions.

Comment: @LoïcFévrier Good point. If the boolean are random the average time is O(log N)

Comment: Not O(log N) but O(1), specifically 2. One can use the formula `sum(i*(1/2)^i, i=1..infinity)` the probability to have to look at exactly K booleans beeing (1/2)^K (ie, true K-1 times and then false).

Answer (score 1):

Complexity of algorithm is **O(N)**.

If you need average amound of iterations it will be (1/1 + 1/2 + 1/4 +.. + 1/N) = (**2 - 1/N**) iterations expected if array with random booleans.

Answer (score 0):

Average case will also be O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Average case would be O(n) as worst case because its array iteration.

Comment: Could you explain better what you mean by "its the array iteration"? thanks!

Comment: you are iterating an array `bs` which always gives O(n) but here additional break may happen anywhere between 1-n or n/2 which becomes O(n/2) = O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Because this is BOOLEAN array I thing average complexity would be constant O(1.5), worst O(n).

Comment: How is this linked with type of array?

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit more? How is this related to the type of the array?

Comment: An average boolean array will have half of elements true, half of elements false. So in average we will find false in first or second element. If array would be for example of type double that would be different.